# In which scenarios cleaning is done in Garbage collector GEN 2

Tags: asp.net, garbage-collection

In ASP.Net, could anybody tell me in which scenarios memory is release from  garbage collector GEN 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simple answer to your question is Generation 2 of tha garbage happens when collections is the large object heap (LOH). When the LOH gets filled, it will trigger a full collection and the Gen2 of the Garbage collector is called.

So  if your application allocates and frees lots of large objects(mostly more than 100k) then that could also be a trigger point.

You may refer this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985011.aspx) for details.

From [Large Object Heap Uncovered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx)

> **From a generation point of view, large objects belong to generation 2
>   because they are collected only when there is a generation 2
>   collection.** When a generation is collected, all younger generations
>   are also collected. So for example, when a generation 1 garbage
>   collection happens, both generation 1 and 0 are collected. And when a
>   generation 2 garbage collection happens, the whole heap is collected.
>   For this reason, a generation 2 garbage collection is also known as a
>   full garbage collection. In this column I will use the term generation
>   2 garbage collection instead of full garbage collection, but they are
>   interchangeable.

[image]

> The figure illustrates that after a generation 2 garbage collection in
>   which you saw that Obj1 and Obj2 were dead, I formed one free space
>   out of the memory that used to be occupied by Obj1 and Obj2, which
>   then was used to satisfy the allocation request for Obj4. The space
>   after the last object Obj3 until the end of the segment can still be
>   used to satisfy further allocation requests.

Answer (score 2):

Garbage collection occurs when one of the following conditions is true:

1. The system has low physical memory.
2. The memory that is used by allocated objects on the managed heap surpasses an acceptable threshold. This threshold is continuously adjusted as the process runs.
3. The GC.Collect method is called. In almost all cases, you do not have to call this method, because the garbage collector runs continuously. This method is primarily used for unique situations and testing.

Generation 2. This generation contains long-lived objects. An example of a long-lived object is an object in a server application that contains static data that is live for the duration of the process.

Garbage collections occur on specific generations as conditions warrant. Collecting a generation means collecting objects in that generation and all its younger generations. A generation 2 garbage collection is also known as a full garbage collection, because it reclaims all objects in all generations (that is, all objects in the managed heap).

A marking phase that finds and creates a list of all live objects.
A relocating phase that updates the references to the objects that will be compacted.

A compacting phase that reclaims the space occupied by the dead objects and compacts the surviving objects. The compacting phase moves objects that have survived a garbage collection toward the older end of the segment.

Because generation 2 collections can occupy multiple segments, objects that are promoted into generation 2 can be moved into an older segment. Both generation 1 and generation 2 survivors can be moved to a different segment, because they are promoted to generation 2.

Ordinarily, the large object heap is not compacted, because copying large objects imposes a performance penalty. However, starting with the .NET Framework 4.5.1, you can use the GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode property to compact the large object heap on demand.

The garbage collector uses the following information to determine whether objects are live:

1. Stack roots. Stack variables provided by the just-in-time (JIT) compiler and stack walker.
2. Garbage collection handles. Handles that point to managed objects and that can be allocated by user code or by the common language runtime.
3. Static data. Static objects in application domains that could be referencing other objects. Each application domain keeps track of its static objects.

Before a garbage collection starts, all managed threads are suspended except for the thread that triggered the garbage collection.
The following illustration shows a thread that triggers a garbage collection and causes the other threads to be suspended. Thread that triggers a garbage collection.

Comment: I'm rephrasing my question.  Could you tell me in which all scenarios object memory will be released from GC GEN2